# Source code handover training

Tags: release

We have to train the client professionals on the source code for an application we developed. What shall I include in their training plan for source code? Any help would be really appreciated.

regards

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200442/dos-and-donts-of-a-technical-presentation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793/good-tips-for-a-technical-presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) If possible show them various changes/revisions the code has gone through, then that will help them to understand the code design at some higher level. (That function needs to be modified for what feature?)

2.) Extract some function Call-Graph/Function-flow diagram using some tool and let them get familiar with that.

3.) The test setup for the application should be explained to them.

4.) High level Design & Low level design document

-AD

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

[What are the core elements to include in Support Documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205374/what-are-the-core-elements-to-include-in-support-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You could highlight the important design decisions. So they understand why you have chosen which solution.